# GridView Row styles and attributes not rendered

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a style and add row behavior to my GridView in the OnRowDataBound event (change the cursor and add onmouseover and onmouseout to highlight a row). When I use an HtmlTextWriter to show the markup of the row within that method everything looks fine. However, in the page source on the browser side, my <tr> elements simply don't have the attributes at all. If I dump the markup in the OnPreRender or OnPreRender complete events of the page, I find that my changes have disappeared by that point. What's going on here?

I am using VS2010 Professional and targeting the 3.5 framework.

UPDATE: I tried some different things to determine where things are going wrong. I subclassed both GridView and GridViewRow so that I could get in front of some of the method calls to determine when my settings get blasted. It turned out to be in GridView.RenderControls() that my attributes were dropped. I don't understand this as there are dozens of examples (including on this site) of adding javascript events using this technique. I ended up having success by overriding the RenderControl() method in my subclass and using it to call base.Render() rather than base.RenderControl()... strange but true.

Comment: I think you're experiencing the same problem as in this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915248/adding-css-class-on-rowdatabound try applying the routines in a later event such as GridView.OnDataBound - travrse each row in the grid make your changes as required and see if that works for you and is performant enough.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having success by subclassing GridView and then overriding the RenderControl() method in my subclass and using it to call base.Render() rather than base.RenderControl()... strange but true.